# Derive same X25519 public from either Ed25519-public or Ed25519-secret

Tags: libsodium, ed25519, x25519

My fictional user only has knowledge of an unclamped Ed25519 public key. He wants to calculate the same X25519 public key that I myself got from my Ed25519 secret.

So, given an Ed25519 key pair, I am looking for a way to get to the *same* X25519 public key in both of these two scenarios:

1. when *converting* an *unclamped* Ed25519 public key to X25519
2. when *deriving* the X25519 public key from the Ed25519 secret

---

**It works with clamped**

I have a Ed25519 key pair `ed_pk` and `ed_sk` where the public key is **clamped**:

```
// ed_sk=5BAA0D..
// ed_pk=466EC8..
```

... and I derive an X25519 public key `x_pk` **from the Ed25519 secret**:

```
crypto_scalarmult_base(x_pk, ed_sk);
// x_pk=1321BF..
```

Note the value of **x_pk**. It matches what I get when converting over **from the Ed25519 public key**:

```
crypto_sign_ed25519_pk_to_curve25519(x_pk, ed_pk);
// x_pk=1321BF..
```

**1321BF..** either way - Great!

---

But when I have an **unclamped** Ed25519 public key to begin with:

```
crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_base_noclamp(ed_pk, ed_sk);
```

... the conversion creates a different number for **x_pk**:

```
// ed_pk=A63B27..
crypto_sign_ed25519_pk_to_curve25519(x_pk, ed_pk);
// x_pk=B9FD38..
```

**Can I (A) convert a public key that wasn't clamped to its clamped version? or (B) amend the Ed25519-X25519 conversion in a way that gets me matching results when working with unclamped variants?**

Comment: What is an *unclamped Ed25519 key*? Ed25519 key generation according to RFC8032 always involves clamping ([here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8032#section-5.1.5), step 2). So, was the public key generated as described in RFC8032 and simply omitted step 2 (and if so, why) or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes. I added the `noclamp` function call to my question.

Comment: AFAIK, clamping is primarily required for X25519 for security reasons, less for Ed25519 itself. Converting an Ed25519 key pair to an X25519 key pair without clamping would therefore be insecure. So I would not be surprised if it is not supported. And if you implement it yourself, you risk insecure X25519 keys.

Comment: One (only apparent) way to derive the clamped from the unclamped key is to determine the scalar s, s. [RFC8032](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8032#section-5.1.5) and thus the first 32 bytes of the SHA512 hash of the seed. From this, the clamped key could then be computed as usual. But it's in the nature of public key cryptography that the private cannot be determined from the public key. Now I'm not a mathematician and cannot exclude that there is other tricky way. Maybe this is a question for other SE communities (cryptography or math).

Comment: @Topaco https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/509.pdf under very specific rules,

Comment: Please paste a complete code sample of what you are trying. Note that under the hood, it is only the secret key that is clamped or not clamped prior to performing the scalar mult to turn it into a public key.

Comment: You would need an unclamped multiplication for Curve25519 as well. There's no such function in libsodium. There's an implementation in the "curve25519-noclamp" branch but it was never merged, because actual use cases are not very common.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely want to use the same key for both operations, you can use Edwards25519 for key exchange instead of complicating the protocol with Curve25519 conversions.

What is often confused as the Ed25519 secret is the seed. The actual secret scalar is usually not exposed in APIs, and handled internally by computing `SHA-512(seed)`, and truncating the output to the first 256 bits.

Here's simple Zig code that does what you want:

```
const std = @import("std");
const crypto = std.crypto;
const Curve25519 = crypto.ecc.Curve25519;
const Edwards25519 = crypto.ecc.Edwards25519;

pub fn main() !void {
    // Generate a random Ed25519 secret seed
    var ed25519_seed: [32]u8 = undefined;
    crypto.random.bytes(&ed25519_seed);

    // In Ed25519, the Edwards25519 secret scalar is SHA-512(seed)[0..32]
    var h: [64]u8 = undefined;
    crypto.hash.sha2.Sha512.hash(&ed25519_seed, &h, .{});
    const edwards25519_secret = Edwards25519.scalar.reduce(h[0..32].*);

    // Unclamped Edwards25519 public key, and Curve25519 projection
    const edwards25519_public = try Edwards25519.basePoint.mul(edwards25519_secret);
    const curve25519_public = try Curve25519.fromEdwards25519(edwards25519_public);

    // Curve25519 secret is the same as the Edwards25519 secret
    const curve25519_secret = edwards25519_secret;
    const curve25519_public2 = try Curve25519.basePoint.mul(curve25519_secret);

    // Both Curve25519 public keys are the same
    std.debug.print("{s}\n{s}\n", .{
        std.fmt.bytesToHex(curve25519_public.toBytes(), .lower),
        std.fmt.bytesToHex(curve25519_public2.toBytes(), .lower),
    });
}
```